# How to open a specific folder when debugging VS Code extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I've developed an extension that reads a directory's `package.json` file. For the extension to work, you must be inside of a JavaScript file. I'm attempting to test this extension by using a test directory inside of the extension's `src` directory that houses a `package.json` file and an `index.js` file.

My goal is to allow the test to open the directory, open the `index.js` file and the run the tests there. This way the test directory goes anywhere the extension goes and the tests are predictable based on the `package.json` file I put into place.

How do I get the tests to open that test directory and run the tests from that specific `index.js` file?

Answer (score 12):

I figured it out. I had to add the path to the directory into `"args"` array of the Extension Test object in `launch.json`.

```
"args": [
  "${workspaceFolder}/src/test/test-directory/",
  "${workspaceFolder}/src/test/test-directory/index.js",
  "--extensionDevelopmentPath=${workspaceFolder}",
  "--extensionTestsPath=${workspaceFolder}/out/test"
]
```

I was also able to have `index.js` open up as well. All of which I realized were totally useless in the tests that I were doing. But at least now I know how to do it and maybe someone else will, too.

Also, if you don't add `${workspaceFolder}` in front of the directory you are referencing, VS Code assumes you want a new file created. So instead of opening the `index.js` file that I had available, it was creating a new empty file named `index.js`.